# R dplyr write function for logical expression in filter

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to automate the logical expression in statements like `dplyr::filter` or `dplyr::case_when`. For a reproducible example consider the `mtcars` and with a special column called `id`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
dd <- mtcars %>% as_tibble() %>% mutate(id = letters[1:32])
```

The goal is to get the same result as with

```r
identifier <- "d"
dd %>%
  filter(id == identifier)
```

by using a function instead of the logical expression, like so

```r
identifier <- "d"
is_id <- function(foo_id){
  # body
}
dd %>%
  filter(is_id(identifier))
```

The goal is to make a function `is_id`, which returns the logical expression used by filter. The function `is_id <- function(car_id){ #body }` should therefore evaluate the expression `dd$id == foo_id` and return the logical vector of its results. This should be achieved without repeating the .data argument (dd in this case) , e.g. not `filter(dd, is_id(dd, "c"))`.

Is there a way to achieve this, and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your data it might not be super performant, but you can use `cur_data_all()` inside your custom function. This function will also work  without the pipe and it can also take several identifiers.

```r
library(dplyr)

dd <- mtcars %>% as_tibble() %>% mutate(id = letters[1:32])

identifier <- "d"

is_id <- function(x){
  dat <- dplyr::cur_data_all()
  dat[["id"]] == x
}

dd %>%
  filter(is_id(identifier))

#> # A tibble: 1 x 12
#>     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb id   
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1  21.4     6   258   110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1 d

idenfifiers <- c("a", "b")
filter(dd, is_id(idenfifiers))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 12
#>     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb id   
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1    21     6   160   110   3.9  2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4 a    
#> 2    21     6   160   110   3.9  2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4 b
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
dd <- mtcars %>% as_tibble() %>% mutate(id = letters[1:32])
                                                     

identifier <- "d"

is_id <- function(x){
  data <- x[, "id"]
  rtn <- data == identifier
  return(rtn)
}

dd %>% 
  filter(is_id(.))

# A tibble: 1 x 12
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb id   
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1  21.4     6   258   110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1 d
```

Comment: Or to make it looks more like your desire code you could always do this: 
`is_id2 <- function(x, y){
  data <- x[, "id"]
  rtn <- data == y
  return(rtn)
}

dd %>% 
  filter(is_id2(., identifier))`